# I'm getting a index list out of range error when I'm trying to run a code that outputs the even numbers within in 2 user inputs

Tags: python-2.7

import math

## Zachary Boyette

```
v = int(raw_input("Enter your smallest #: "))
V = int(raw_input("enter Your largest #: "))
v = v-1
i = 0


def Tough1 () :
    j = 0 
    List = []
    for i in range (v,V) :
        i = i + 1
        List.append (i)
        j = j + 1
        l = 0

    if ((List[j] % 2) - (List[j]/2)) > l :
            List.remove[j]
            print i
```

The line bellow is what its telling me is the error and I'm not sure why

```
Tough1 ()`
#this is done in JGrasp 
print List
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The j is incremented just after the append. Afterwards you access the list item at index j, which is 1 in the first iteration, but the list only has one entry (whose index is 0).

BTW:

```
(List[j] % 2) - (List[j]/2)) > 1
```

is no valid condition for filtering even numbers. The result of

```
(List[j] % 2)
```

this operation is either 0 (even) or 1 (odd). So just use:

```
(List[j] % 2) == 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but it turns out i was supposed to be using a while loop to do it so instead i made a code that adds 2 to the starting value or adds one at first if its neg and then adds 2 inside the loop so it outputs the evens